# How to compare word to word and if matching percentage is above 70%, then load those records into target using Informatica

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have a dataset in this format

```
Column1: 
Mumbai is a capital of MH
```

If the input is `Mumbai is of MH` there is a 70% match to the dataset sting so that dataset record is added to the target table like:

```
Target Table:
Column1: 
Mumbai is a capital of MH
```

If the input is only `Mumbai MH` there is less than a 70% match so the record is **not** added to the target table.

How is this possible using Informatica?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to put your matching logic into a java transformation and then use a filter transformation to only allow records through with a high enough score. This being very similar to master data management I'd also encourage you to look at Informatica MDM

Answer (score 0):

You can take 2 input port for the java transformation as:
Input1:"Mumbai is a capital of MH"
Input2:"Mumbai is of MH"

In the java transformation you can split both the Input string using the split() function and store both the string in an array.

After this you can iterate word by word Input2 array and check if the word exist in Input1 array. After you get the matching record you can calculate the percentage.